# sitecore error - only local urls allowed

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I had to navigate to kickuser.aspx to kick a user out. After I selected the user I want to kick out, I got the following error.

[image]

The page URL at this point was :

```
http://[Websiteroot]/sitecore/shell/Applications/Login/Users/Kick.aspx?url=http%3a%2f%2f[Websiteroot]%2fsitecore%2fshell%2fApplications%2fLogin%2fUsers%2fUsers.aspx%3fsu%3d%252Fsitecore%252Fshell%252Fdefault.aspx%253Fsc_lang%253Den%26inv%3d1
```

The query string wasn't decoded  - not sure if that is the cause.

Also, regardless of what user I log in as, I get this error. I have never encountered this before.

Comment: Have you seen this blog post? Does it help? https://sitecorethrob.wordpress.com/2016/04/12/only-local-urls-are-allowed-user-profile-starturl/

Comment: Yes @AdrianIorgu - that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Reflector shows that Kick.aspx has next code under the hood:

```
string queryString = WebUtil.GetQueryString("url");
if (WebUtil.IsExternalUrl(queryString))
{
    throw new SecurityException("Only local URLs are allowed.");
}
base.Response.Redirect(queryString);
```

WebUtil.IsExternalUrl checks that "://" is present in your url get parameter (Actually it doesn't matter if it is encoded or not. "://" and "%3a%2f%2f" have same behavior)

The problem is that you somehow was transferred to page Kick.aspx?**url=http://**...
You can try to get rid of *"url"* GET parameter(or remove *"http://[Websiteroot]"* to make path local):

http://[Websiteroot]/sitecore/shell/Applications/Login/Users/Kick.aspx

then you should be able to kick users.

Comment: Cheers @anton, don't know how I missed that! How to get rid of 'url' GET parameter or make the path local? Do I need to change some settings?

Comment: The url in the user's profile is empty. Do you know where it is generated from?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug. The exception you get is indeed because of the query parameter "url". Sitecore attempts a redirect to whatever the value of this parameter, and it makes no attempt at decoding it before the redirect.

`this.Response.Redirect(WebUtil.GetQueryString("url"));`

However. This functionality happens AFTER the actual Kick(), so the functionality should work as expected; only failing to redirect you back to the point of origin.

Comment: This apparently works out of the box and I have changed nothing for the query string to be encoded/decoded?